# Google Closure XhrIo PROGRESS EventType

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I registered a `EventType.PROGRESS` listener along with a `EventType.COMPLETE`listener to a XhrIo object. I call the `XhrIo.send` method post some form data. The `COMPLETE` listener fires as expected. But the `PROGRESS` listener never seems to fire (I also tried `UPLOAD_PROGRESS`, `DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS`, and `INCREMENTAL_DATA`, but no luck).

I searched for code examples but (surprisingly) couldn't find any.

Has anyone ever used the google closure `EventType.PROGRESS` successfully before?

- https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.net.EventType.html
- https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.net.XhrIo.html

Comment: How do you register the event listener?

Comment: Also, what browsers are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to work:

```
goog.events.listen(xhr, goog.net.EventType.PROGRESS,
  (progressEvent) => {
    console.log('Downloaded ' + progressEvent.loaded + '/' + progressEvent.total);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new XhrIo instance and accessing the original `xhr` object via the `xhr_` property? Then it's possible to listen to the progress event, and report on progress. On my localhost, I get strange results when sending data i.e., the loaded is just some numbers and total is 0.

```
const xhr = goog.net.XhrIo.send('/api/upload/test-api', () => {
  const obj = xhr.getResponseJson()
}, 'POST', base64encoded)
goog.events.listen(xhr.xhr_, 'progress', ({ event_ }) => {
   console.log('Uploaded ' + event_.loaded + '/' + event_.total)
})
```